# Zend Framework 1.12 Basket with Cookies

Tags: php, cookies, zend-framework

I have built a Basket using Cookies within a Zend 1.12 Application. I am NOT using the Zend_Header_SetCookie i am using the php setcookie functionality.

When the basket has been checked out an order is created. What i would like to do is if you open a page with the basket and the OrderId is in the URL then it should load the Order and populate the cookie for the basket.

The basket on the page will loop through the items in the basket cookie and render each line item. But when i load the Order and populate the basket the cookie actually isnt set as expected.

My original thought was that the headers have probably already been sent so the cookie wouldnt be sent with it. I've trying to use the various hooks: preDispatch etc... but i cant seem to get this working.

If this wont work, can you think of another way that i can take an existing order and populate a cookie from it that can then be dropped.

Comment: So anyone can view anyone else's basket simply by editing the URL parameter? Also, I'm not sure why you're storing the basket contents in both the database and the cookie - why do both? To actually help figure out why what you currently have isn't working we'd need to see some code.

Comment: @TimFountain no i'm not that silly, it checks to see if the user is valid before doing anything first. So that's at least solved. In terms of code, i'll try and work out what i can publish here. One of the issues related to this has been resolved --- my "basket" class was only ever allowing 1 item to be added. vs allow for multiple adds.

Comment: @TimFountain Other than the solution i have can you think of a better way? The reason i'm doing it this way is to reduce the number of screens and the like so that the same screen is used for both creating the order (basket) and amending it.